# Convert a C++ class into a Java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javacpp

I've been learning JavaCPP for a project using Eclipse, and I created a Java project for the application. But when I try to create a class in the `/src/main/resources` directory, it can't find any folders and says "no entries available".

Comment: First of all you need to crate maven project not java project (maven is a build tool for java). 2. /src/main/resources is a maven default location for resources - i.e. text files, icon images or any another files you application may need. 3. Please read javacpp manual i.e. README.md setp by step https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp

Comment: See also [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) - [using maven in eclipse IDE](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html)

Comment: It's actually easier to use the build plugin from Gradle JavaCPP:
https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#getting-started